# i want to add a particular product to cart using flask,html but i have displayed all the products using simple select query

Tags: python, flask, sqlplus, cart

when i click a addtocart button i want to retrive its product id but i am getting error as its selecting all pid as all the product have same button id how do i solve this .i want to get pid of only the one which user has clicked.please help

````
 ```


    
        {% extends 'navbar.html' %}
    
        {% block title %}
        <title>agroproducts</title>
        {%  endblock title %}
        {% block css %}
     
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/assets/css/agroproducts.css" />
      <script src="static/assets/js/cart.js" async></script>
      {% endblock css %}
      
      {% block body %}  
      
        {% for p in res %}
        
          <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
              <span></span>
              <div class="content">
                <h2>productname: {{p[2]}} </h2>
                <p>Owner : {{p[0]}}</p>
                <p>Email : {{p[1]}}</p>
                
                
                <p>productdesc:{{p[3]}}</p>
                <p>Price : {{p[4]}}</p>
                <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                <form action="{{url_for('cart')}}" methods="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="pid" >
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value={{p[2]}} >add to cart</button>
                
              
    
    
    
      
        
          
          
            
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        
        
    
      
        {% endfor%}
    
      
      {% endblock body %}
       
    
    flask code
    
    @app.route("/cart",methods=['POST','GET'])
    def addToCart():
          pid = request.form.get('pid')
          conn=cx_Oracle.connect(user="SYSTEM",password="bnm")
        
          cur = conn.cursor()
          cur.execute("SELECT bid FROM buser WHERE email ='{0}'". format(session['email']))
          
          bid = cur.fetchone()[0]
          try:
               
    
               execute=("INSERT INTO cart VALUES (:pid,bid)")
               cur.execute(execute,{'pid':pid,'bid':bid})
               conn.commit()
               print("Added successfully")
          except:
               conn.rollback()
               print( "Error occured")
               conn.close()
          return redirect(url_for('root'))```
````

when i click a addtocart button i want to retrive its product id but i am getting error as its selecting all pid as all the product have same button id how do i solve this .i want to get pid of only the one which user has clicked.please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have posted

1. You don't have any button with an id
2. When you submit your form, the only thing you are submitting is a single input (it's hidden) whose name is "pid" and that input has no value.
3. I don't see the closing form tag

You can change your code to (and this isn't really optimal) to

```
    <form action="{{url_for('cart')}}" methods="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="{{p[2]}}">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">add to cart</button>
    </form>
```

With the above code, you now have an input field with a name of "pid" whose value is `p[2]` which I assume is the product id. When you click on `add to cart`, just that particular form will be submitted and in the backend you can retrieve the value by looking for the value of the element named `pid`